# Fetch Api unable to get Session from PHP server

Tags: javascript, php, session, fetch-api

I am using Fetch Api in my application.

I've got a PHP server page to get session data which was already defined before. It seemd like this:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

session_start();
// $_SESSION['data'] already defined before
$result = array();
// print_r($_SESSION['data']);
if (isset($_SESSION['data'])) {
  $result = $_SESSION['data'];
  $result['code'] = 'ok';
} else {
  $result['code'] = 'error';
}
echo json_encode($result, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE|JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

I also got another html page to get the session data. It seemd like this:

```
  <script>
    $(function() {
      // use $.ajax
      $.ajax({
          url: 'session.php',
          dataType: 'json'
        })
        .done(function(res) {
          console.log(res);
        });
      // end

      // use fetch
      fetch('session.php').then(function(res) {
        if (res.ok) {
          res.json().then(function(obj) {
            console.log(obj);
          });
        }
      });
      // end
    });
  </script>
```

The problem is, when I use $.ajax(), session data can be correctly showed. But when I use fetch(), the session data was undefined.

So, what goes wrong and how can I fix it? Thanks!

Comment: You use `ajax` but don't passed `session_id` and `start_session` starting new session. But when you request on browser this script you session_id saved in browser cookie and you can get correct session.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you want `fetch` to send cookies, you have to provide the `credentials` option.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalFetch/fetch#Parameters for details.

Comment: credentials can be set to 'same-origin'

Comment: When providing the credentials option, what is the difference between 'include' and 'same-origin'? I cannot seem to find this info anywhere.

Comment: @kojow7 [Check the MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) (I tried to copy-paste here but it was a mess). Basically, relevant example for this answer, with 'include', mysite.com could get a session from yoursite.com but with 'same-origin' mysite.com couldn't get yoursite.com's session.

Answer (score 2):

jquery ajax is a usual ajax request and the browser is sending the cookie header with the session id that identify your session.

fetch doesnt - instead a new session is created with out any data
send the php session id either with url or header

have a look at: http://php.net/manual/en/session.idpassing.php